# Java crash troubleshooting

Tags: java, crash, autohotkey, native-code, java-native-interface

I'm working with a structure that allows me to run AHK code in java, I've been getting an error after about 3-5 minutes after starting. I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions of where I should debug

```
    #
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x61308396, pid=9820, tid=7128
    #
    # JRE version: 7.0_17-b02
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
    # Problematic frame:
    # V  [jvm.dll+0x148396]
    #
    # Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
    #
    # An error report file with more information is saved as:
    # C:\Users\Preston\IdeaProjects\jBot\hs_err_pid9820.log
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
    # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
    # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
    #
```

hs_err_pid9820.log: http://pastebin.com/T7yhGNti

```
public static boolean control() {
    try {
        NativeCall.init();
        init();
        return true;
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("\n" + "Something went wrong...");
        return false;
    }
}


public static void init() {
    IntCall textdll = new IntCall("AutoHotkey.dll", "ahktextdll");
    textdll.executeCall(new Object[]{"", "", ""});
    exec = new IntCall("AutoHotkey.dll", "ahkExec");
}

public static void ahk(String code) {
        exec.executeCall(code);
}
```

Full Source code: http://pastebin.com/ndrnX4a1

Comment: Do you have source code that caused this?  These sorts of errors aren't useful unless you're editing the JVM code directly.

Comment: Can you point to what you mean by AHK code? You're somehow accessing memory the JVM doesn't have access to; we probably can't debug too well without knowing what source you're executing.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys, I added the methods that I've created to send the code. This is where all the AutoHotKey interaction happens. I've been using this to run AutoHotkey commands, passing variables back and forth from java and AutoHotkey.

Comment: Don't use pastebin. Post only the relevant part of your code directly in your question. If you feel the need to use pastebin, it is a clear indication that you are trying to post way more code that you probably need and should.

Comment: Bruno, I will edit it, and post only the code that I THINK is causing the problem, I posted the source only because it was asked for, and because of my little experience with java crashes, I was attempting to provide as much info as possible.

Comment: Retagged. I think this is going to be hard to fix without AHK sourcecode and information about `IntCall`

Comment: Here's a bit of info about IntCall http://johannburkard.de/software/nativecall/

I'll start working on getting the AHK source code..